# Почему компилятор не ловит ошибку при неправильной работе с динамической переменной

Tags: c++, dynamic, build-error

```
int *varr = new int(5);

for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
    varr[i] = i;
}
```

Comment: Ну не выполняет он проверку выхода за пределы диапазона. А у вас вообще непонятно - что проверять? Один указатель создали, по другому пишете - что тут не так?

Comment: Исправил, т.е ошибка изза того что new не проверяет выход за пределы, и условно я могу выстрелить себе в ногу пользуясь переменной как массивом?

Comment: А при чем тут new? Выход за пределы массива происходит внутри цикла. Заботиться о том, чтобы такого не происходило - обязанность программиста.

Comment: Да запросто. Это язык, который эффективность ставит выше ошибок программиста :)

Comment: А почему компилятор позволяет работать с динамической переменной как с массивом? это же обычный тип int

Comment: Нет, это **указатель** на `int`. Соответственно количество элементов, на которое он указывает, никак не ограничено, а оператор индексирования `p[i]` работает эквивалентно `*(p + i)`

Comment: благодарю, т.е компилятору пофиг переменная это или массив, ошибки возникнут только при выполнении?

Comment: Переменная здесь только `varr`, но она является указателем, а указывает она на массив из нескольких `int`, на массив из одного `int` или на отдельное значение `int`, компилятор никак не контролирует. А ошибка тут сразу запарывает весь код еще на этапе компиляции, так как некорретный доступ к памяти является Неопределенным Поведением. То есть программа может не скомпилироваться совсем или выдавать рандомные результаты при работе.

Comment: благодарствую. +1 вам в карму:)

Comment: Добавлю к вышенаписанному: если вам нужно отслеживать подобные ошибки, вам может помочь cppcheck и sinitizer. Первая поможет отлавливать похожие ошибки во время компиляции (ну или во время проверки кода), а вторая крашанет вашу прогу во время выполнения и выведет ошибки вроде обращения по невалидному указателю,выходу за пределы массива и утечек памяти.

Comment: Массивы переменной длины в C++ так и не сделали, даже запретили. Результатом оператора **new[]** всё равно возвращается указатель на первый элемент. Чтобы у вас была гарантия отсутствия баг-описок, пользуйтесь **std::vector<int> vec(5)**

Comment: @AlexGlebe Ага, хорошая такая гарантия. В цикле выход за пределы массива как был, так и останется.

Comment: @VTT Выход за пределы это уже не описка, а жёсткий баг. А же не буду намекать на функцию `std::vector::at`, вдруг обидятся.

Comment: Формулировка неверная, в C++ нет динамических переменных. В Вашем примере используется переменная указатель.

Answer (score 2):

Компилятор не ловит ошибку, потому что такой цели перед ним не ставится. Для тех, кто может не сразу видит проблему в коде, поясню. Запись вида:

```
int *varr = new int(5);
```

приводит к выделению в куче одной единственной переменной типа `int` (не массив), и инициализации этой переменной числом `5`. Таким образом, дальнейшие попытки заполнить массив по указателю `varr` с выходом за пределы этого одного единственного элемента приводят к неопределённому поведению. С++ не различает сырые указатели на скалярные типы от указателей, за которыми скрывается массив таких объектов.

Если хочется максимально обезопасить себя от проблем выхода за границы массива, стоит использовать хотя бы `std::vector` и функцию доступа к элементам [`at`](https://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/at). В таком случае, обращение по невалидным индексам сгенерирует исключение, которое можно будет перехватить. Однако всё это по-прежнему будет работать только в процессе выполнения программы. Для того, чтобы найти подобные ошибки в коде как можно раньше, следует воспользоваться всевозможными программами статического анализа кода. Самые очевидные примеры, это [CppCheck](http://cppcheck.sourceforge.net/) и [Clang Static Analyzer](https://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/).