# Почему код работает?

Tags: c++

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void innermostFun(int* ptrValue)
{
    *ptrValue = 10;
}

int* middleFun(int* ptrValue)
{
    innermostFun(ptrValue);
    int someValue = 15;
    return &someValue;
}

int main()
{
    int value = 0;
    int* invalidPtr = middleFun(&value);
    cout << *invalidPtr;
    return 0;
}
```

Собственно то почему этот код должен выбросить ошибку написано в статье: http://scrutator.me/post/2015/12/30/pointers_demystified_p2.aspx.
Почему у меня `cout << *invalidPtr;` не бросает ошибку?

Comment: на `C++` слова должен по отношению к `UB` неприменимы.

Comment: Случайно он у вас работает. Так получилось. Кроме того, нормальный компилятор должен выдать что-то вроде `warning: address of local variable ‘someValue’ returned [-Wreturn-local-addr]`.

Comment: gcc и предупреждение показал, и приложение честно упало. Хотя не обязано. А clang хоть и ругнулся, но приложение не упало.

Comment: Я думал vs нормальный компилятор.

Comment: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/BA5vDE тут может чуть понятнее станет почему случайно не упало)

Comment: @midia vs же выдает `warning C4172: returning address of local variable or temporary: someValue` - вполне нормально

Comment: @midia: Что за странные ожидания? Поведение этого кода никак не зависит от "нормальности компилятора". Никто вам не обещал тут никакого "выбрасывания ошибок", что бы там ни было написано в какой-то статье. В мире С++ не существует вопроса "Почему код работает?" Всякий раз, когда у вас возникает такой вопрос , это означает, что вы что-то неправильно понимаете.

Answer (score 4):

Вы возвращаете указатель на локальную переменную `someValue`, которая после выхода из функции не существует:

```
int* middleFun(int* ptrValue)
{
    innermostFun(ptrValue);
    int someValue = 15;
    return &someValue;
}
```

Дальнейшие попытки чтения/записи значения по этому указателю приводят к [неопределённому поведению](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/900292/176217). Но в реальной жизни, скорее всего при чтении вы получите какой-либо мусор или некоторое служебное значение, установленное компилятором для отладочного режима работы.

Answer (score 2):

Небольшой пример:

```
class task {
public:
    explicit task(int _priority)
        : m_priority(_priority)
    {}

public:
    int priority_a() const { return m_priority; }
    int priority_b() const { return 0x00; }

protected:
    int m_priority;
};

task* create_task() {
    task t { 0xFF };
    return &t;
}

int main() {
    task *t = create_task();
    t->priority_b();
    return t->priority_a();
}
```

Скомпилировал с флагом `-fomit-frame-pointer`(спасибо @vladnimof), оптимизация выключена.

Метод `task::priority_a`:

```
mov QWORD PTR [rsp-8], rdi       // извлекаем указатель на объект
mov rax, QWORD PTR [rsp-8]       // ... и как-то его используем
mov eax, DWORD PTR [rax]
ret
```

Метод `task::priority_b`:

```
mov QWORD PTR [rsp-8], rdi       // извлекаем указатель на объект
mov eax, 0                       // ... но никак его не используем
ret
```

Функция `main`:

```
sub rsp, 24
call create_task()
mov QWORD PTR [rsp+8], rax       // поместили указатель на объект в стек
mov rax, QWORD PTR [rsp+8]       // прочитали из стека :)
mov rdi, rax                     // передали как первый аргумент
call task::priority_b() const
mov rax, QWORD PTR [rsp+8]       // аналогично
mov rdi, rax                     // аналогично
call task::priority_a() const
nop
add rsp, 24
ret
```

Функция `create_task`:

```
sub rsp, 24
lea rax, [rsp+12]
mov esi, 255
mov rdi, rax
call task::task(int)
mov eax, 0                       // А в eax то уже ноль!
add rsp, 24
ret
```

Answer (score 0):

Так как внутренние переменные хранятся в стеке и программы ничто не зачищают (оптимизаторы ещё те) то можно хакнуть какую нибудь функцию на пароли / номера карточек и т.д. Ваш код будет работать до тех пока оптимизация компилятора всё не испортит.  Чтобы ваш код работал нужно переменную делать **volatile** (Выполнить несмотря ни на что - есть!). Вот работающий пример использовать память не по назначению:

```
// > g++ -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -Os stacksecret.cpp
// > g++ -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -Os -S stacksecret.cpp
// warning: address of local variable ‘s’ returned [-Wreturn-local-addr]

# include <iostream>
typedef
struct ssecret {
int x ;
int y ;
}
secret ;

secret * f  ( ) {
  secret s ;
  s . x = 666 ;
  s . y = 999 ; 
  return & s ; }
/*  leaq    -8(%rsp), %rax
    ret */

secret volatile * v  ( ) {
  secret volatile s ;
  s . x = 666 ;
  s . y = 999 ; 
  return & s ; }    
  /*movl    $666, -8(%rsp)
    leaq    -8(%rsp), %rax
    movl    $999, -4(%rsp)
    ret  */

int main  ( ) {
  secret * ns = f ( ) ;
  std::cout<<"x = "<< ns->x <<" , y = "<< ns->y << std::endl;
      ns -> x = 0 ;
      ns -> y = 0 ;
  secret volatile * s = v ( ) ;
  /*movl    $666, 8(%rsp)
    movl    $999, 12(%rsp)*/
      std::cout<<"x = "<< s->x <<" , y = "<< s->y << std::endl;
      s -> x = 0 ;
      s -> y = 0 ;
  /*movl    $0, 8(%rsp)
    movl    $0, 12(%rsp)
    addq    $24, %rsp*/
 }
```

---Вывод---

```
>./a.out 
x = 0 , y = 0
x = 666 , y = 999
```

В ассемблерном коде видно, что несмотря на оптимизацию в стек всё-таки ставят значения. Функция **v** возвращает `StackPointer-8` как адрес локальной переменной структуры. И можно пользоваться этими данными как угодно. (Раз ничьё - значит моё!) Правильно использовать **volatile** надо чтобы зачищать память. Вот функция **main** чистит , знает порядок.

Ваш код не должен падать, так как когда вызывали функцию , там хватало места в стеке, поэтому любой доступ к этим ячейкам памяти свободный, а если компилятор постарается, то вообще к памяти дотрагиваться не будет. Но гарантий сохранности данных нет, так как любая функция может использовать стек по своему усмотрению.

Answer (score 0):

Данный код называется опасным и, да, может привести к неопределенному поведению. Но, в принципе, такой код не просто может работать, а даже может работать правильно, что часто приводит к тяжело отыскиваемой ошибке. Его, конечно, практиковать не стоит.

Просто, основываясь на том, что программе определяется место для стека. А параметры функций передаются в основном через стек, если конечно не указан другой способ передачи, то после выхода из функции и до вызова следующей стек остается, как правило, нетронутым. Там по сути смещается только указатель. А так как мы вернули адрес в стеке, то мы можем по нему получить нормальное значение уже практически несуществующей переменной. Конечно если сразу вызвать другую функцию, то значение наверняка будет затерто. Другими словами если стек не трогать, то значение в нем может жить вполне определенное время.

Практически следующий код будет без проблем выполняться правильно:

```
int *Func()
 {
    int a = 10;
    return &a;
 }

void main()
 {
   int vvv = *Func(); // vvv будет = 10
 }
```

Пользоваться такой возможностью безусловно не рекомендуется.

Отвечая на Ваш вопрос, указанный Вами код работает именно по этой причине.

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка здесь совсем не обязательна, так как паять-то освобождена, но доступ к ней может не только не закрыться, но память даже могла быть выделена повторно, причём, тому же процессу. Но вот что там валяется и валяется ли? Гарантировать работу этого кода вообще и какое-то конкретное его поведение в частности нельзя.