# C++ аллокация памяти

Tags: c++, память

```
#include <iostream>

void main() {
  void* ptr = malloc(3);
  int *b = static_cast<int*>(ptr);
  *b = 2147483647;
  std::cout << *b; // 2147483647
}
```

У меня есть 3 байта пам'яти от malloc и sizeof(int*) показывает 4, каким образом я поместил int в 3 байта без ошибок? Компилятор MS Visual C++

Comment: Аналогия - "я тут перешел дорогу в неположенном месте, и меня не сбила машина - как такое могло произойти?..."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ваш код содержит неопределённое поведение (UB) - запись за границы выделенной памяти. От компилятора не требуется уведомлять о подобного рода ошибках. Подробнее об UB можете почитать в соответствующем вопросе: [Разница между неопределённым, неспецифицированным и зависимым от реализации поведением](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/900268/176217)

Answer (score 2):

Этот код вызывает неопределенное поведение.

Ошибка не гарантируется, и эффект может быть любым (в том числе программа может работать как будто ничего не произошло, а может неожиданно сломаться).