# unsigned char* и char* при работе со строками

Tags: c++

Могут ли возникнуть проблемы с работой со строками если использовать не `char* /const char*`, а `unsigned char*/const unsigned char*`? 
Если все правильно, к примеру, в `UTF-8`, каждый символ имеет свой индекс в диапазоне от `1-255`. В случае в `char*` диапазон будет другой.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Несмотря на то, что `char`, `unsigned char` и `signed char` - это три разных типа, представление простого `char` может быть как знаковым, так и беззнаковым. Это определяется реализацией компилятора. Поэтому говорить о каких-то проблемах можно лишь с учётом конкретного компилятора и функции, обрабатывающей массив таких символов (строк в данной интерпретации). Например, для функций из `<cctype>`, в частности [`std::isalnum`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isalnum) требуется чтобы символ был представим диапазоном `unsigned char` и для безопасного использования требуется соответствующее приведение типа:

> To use these functions safely with plain chars (or signed chars), the argument should first be converted to `unsigned char`

Иначе, результатом может быть [неопределённое поведение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/900268/176217).

Answer (score 3):

В UTF8 символы не имеют индекса в диапазоне 1-255, а занимают от 1 до 6 байт с переносом. Для строк в кодировке UTF8 С++20 вводит отдельный тип `char8_t`.

Comment: Стоит заметить, что `char8_t` описывает кодовую единицу для UTF-8, а не символ в общем случае.