# Возврат сырого массива из функции и последующее удаление?

Tags: c++

Знаю, тема изьезжена. Но все же возник вопрос:

Известно, что в Си строго не рекомендуется возвращать сырой массив из функции, поскольку  функция вернёт не массив, а указатель на него, и потом могут возникнуть проблемы с удалением выделенной памяти:  нет смысла применять `delete` к указателю. Но это же указатель на массив. Почему бы тогда не применить `delete[]`?

```
#include <iostream> 

int *getArray() 
{ 
 int* tab = new int[30]; 
 return tab; 
} 

int main() 
{ 
 int* arrayFromFunction = getArray(); 
 std::cout << arrayFromFunction[0]; 
 delete [] arrayFromFunction; 
}
```

Соответствует ли это стандарту? Есть люди, которые утверждают, что этот вариант вполне рабочий. Можно ли им доверять?

Comment: Единственная проблема, которая может возникнуть - вы забудете вызать `delete[]`. *"функция вернёт не массив, а указатель на него"* А при чем тут функция? `tab` остается указателем (не массивом) даже если не возвращать его из `getArray`.

Comment: Ни в С, ни в С++ возвратить из функции массив нельзя в принципе, в языке просто нет такого синтаксиса. Возвращать указатель - пожалуйста.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat , ну да. Вы правы. Указатель и там, и там. Просто из функции вернётся указатель на тип `int`, а не на массив. Но этот факт мне нисколько не позволяет понять, как сработает к нему `delete[]`

Comment: @Harry , то есть такая конструкция валидна?

Comment: *"из функции вернётся указатель на тип int, а не на массив"* Не понял. Даже если никуда не возвращать `int* tab = new int[30];`, это все равно 'указатель на тип int'. Указатель с типом "указатель на массив" выглядел бы так: `int (*tab)[N];`.

Comment: Да, конечно, все корректно. Вы выделили память с помощью `new[]`, освободили с помощью `delete[]`, все в рамках одного менеджера памяти - так что тут все нормально.

Comment: *"Известно, что в Си строго не рекомендуется возвращать сырой массив из функции"*, а откуда вы это взяли? я ещё могу понять подобное в `c++` ввиду умных указателей, но в `си`...

Comment: @timbars , ну вроде как рекомендуют очищать память там, где выделили (внутри одного метода)

Comment: @Александр да с чего вы это взяли? вот вам самый тупой пример: `malloc`

Comment: Кхм, а не путаете ли вы выделение памяти в библиотеке, а освобождение в приложении? Так да, так делать нельзя, если память выделяла библиотека, то она и должна освобождать эту память, т.е. `new_some` <-> `free_some`, но никак мне вызов `delete` / `free` в приложении которое получило этот указатель на массив, или объект.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<sup>Проблема здесь только в том, что во времена, когда космические корабли бороздят просторы C++17 и уже подлетают к системе C++20, вы занимаетесь ручным управлением памятью.</sup>

Что переменная `tab`, что `arrayFromFunction`, обе они имеют тип `int*`. Да, такой указатель может указывать как на скалярное значение, так и на массив оных. Именно поэтому и возможны вообще ошибки неправильного использования `delete` / `delete[]`. При освобождении памяти всегда надо знать, что лежит по указанному адресу. В вашем случае по адресу всегда размещается массив (выделен через `new[]`), стало быть и удалять его надо через `delete[]`, а не `delete`. Иначе схватите [неопределённое поведение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/900292/176217).

По вашему коду представьте, что функция просто вставилась (`inline`) в место вызова (перестала существовать как вызываемая функция), тогда:

```
int* arrayFromFunction = getArray(); 
std::cout << arrayFromFunction[0]; 
delete [] arrayFromFunction;
```

превратится в:

```
int* arrayFromFunction = new int[30]; 
std::cout << arrayFromFunction[0]; 
delete [] arrayFromFunction;
```

Здесь, я думаю, у вас уже не возникает вопроса в валидности кода. Фактически эти куски кода дают идентичный результат.

Но вот если бы ваша функция `getArray` превратилась в нечто такое:

```
int* getSome(bool c) 
{ 
    if (c) {
        int* tab = new int[30]; 
        return tab; 
    }
    return new int(42);
}
```

То в зависимости от условия `c` возвращался бы либо массив, либо одиночное число. И для всего этого пришлось бы ставить в соответствие правильный вызов `delete` или `delete[]`, чтобы программа оставалась корректной.

Comment: Спасибо за развернутый ответ. Я, кажется, понял, что меня ещё в ней смущало. Получается, что, вернув таким образом указатель на массив, я не смогу программно извне узнать количество выделенных в нем элементов через `sizeof`: `sizeof` вернёт лишь размер указателя (либо первого элемента при разыменовывании). А следовательно я не буду знать границы массива. А не зная его края, не смогу быть уверенным, что вне функции не выйду за границы диапазона при обращении к его элементам... То есть как минимум нужно ещё передать в функцию дополнительный параметр, который будет выносить во вне размер. Я прав?

Comment: @Александр именно поэтому все функции, работающие с сырыми указателями дополнительно принимают параметр, задающий размер. Если, конечно, не ожидается иной признак окончания последовательности, например, нулевой символ с строках.

Answer (score 1):

Верить можно.

Ибо как написано в самой документации:

> Для объектов, не имеющих тип класса (класс, Структураили объединение),
>   вызывается оператор глобального удаления. Для объектов типа класса имя
>   функции освобождения разрешается в глобальной области, если выражение
>   delete начинается с оператора унарного разрешения области (::). В
>   противном случае перед освобождением памяти оператор удаления вызывает
>   деструктор объекта (если указатель не имеет значения null). Оператор
>   удаления можно определять отдельно для каждого класса; если для
>   некоторого класса такое определение отсутствует, вызывается глобальный
>   оператор удаления. Если выражение удаления используется для
>   освобождения объекта класса, статический тип которого имеет
>   виртуальный деструктор, функция освобождение разрешается через
>   виртуальный деструктор динамического типа объекта.

Что позволяет сделать вывод о том, что в вашей ситуации будет вызван просто глобальный оператор удаления.

Функция лишь вернет указатель на определенное место в памяти. И ничем плохим это не грозит.

Comment: Но ничего страшного, что `delete` будет применен к этому указателю, который неизвестно, в какой области памяти находится?

Comment: То есть вернётся не указатель на массив, а указатель на тип `int`

Comment: А почему будет неизвестно, на какой участок памяти он указывает?