# operator++ в std::istream_iterator не итерируется по итератору

Tags: c++, итераторы

Изучаю итератор `std::istream_iterator`. Я пытаюсь проитерироваться по нему. Подскажите, пожалуйста, почему следующий код не работает как ожидается?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iterator>
int main()
{
    std::istringstream str("0.1 0.2 0.3 0.4");
    std::istream_iterator<double> iter(str);
    int n = std::distance(iter, std::istream_iterator<double>());
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        std::cout << *iter << std::endl;
        ++iter;
    }
}
```

Как результат, выводится первый элемент 4 раза:

```
0.1
0.1
0.1
0.1
```

Comment: Но ведь, в 11-ой строчке кода я уже это сделал ++iter; ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Все давольно просто: давайте немного модифицируем ваш пример

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iterator>
int main()
{
    std::istringstream str("0.1 0.2 0.3 0.4");
    std::istream_iterator<double> iter(str);

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        std::cout << *iter << std::endl;
        ++iter;
    }
}
```

Я убрал `distance` и в цикле выставил константное значение. Что мы видим в `output`:

```
0.1
0.2
0.3
0.4
```

Это явно означает то, что `distance` изменяет наш итератор! Но `distance` должна копировать его, как так получилось? Дело в том, что конструктор копирования `istream_iterator` [тривиален](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/istream_iterator/istream_iterator) а значит при изменении копии у нас будет "как бы меняться" оригинал. Это связано с тем, что этот итератор завязан именно на `stream`, а в них вы не можете хранить состояние.

Comment: Спасибо за подробный ответ! А как же тогда узнать количество элементов для std::istream_iterator, не используя std::distance ?

Comment: @Chudvan по-моему никак. Можете задать по этому поводу отдельный вопрос, может есть такая возможноть. Хотя, например, в данном конкретном случае, вы можете создать два итератора: один для определения дистанции, другой для обхода. Но стоит заменить стоку на поток ввода - и это работать не будет

Comment: Причина не в том, что istream_iterator тривиален, а в том, что при копировании,  происходит связывание с копируемым итератором через хранимый указатель, а именно, указатель инициализируется адресом этого итератора, а не с его указателем.

Comment: @ARHovsepyan я не знаю как происходит копирование этого объекта, но в документации вполне четко сказано, что конструктор копирования может быть (читай "является") тривиальным - достаточно знать это, чтобы понять в чем проблема. К тому же (учитывая что даже согласно документации тривиальность конструктора копирования `istream_iterator` не является обязательной) реализация для разных компиляторов может отличаться

Comment: все это верно, но не в этом причина того, что "distance изменяет наш итератор"

Comment: @ARHovsepyan поэтому я и написал:  "как бы меняться"  - двойные кавычки и "как бы" должны ясно дать понять, что это не так, хотя выглядит похожим на это

Comment: Причём здесь вообще тривиальность копирующего конструктора?

Answer (score 1):

Проблема в том, что `std::istream_iterator` является итератором ввода ([input iterator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator)). Это значит, что с помощью такого итератора можно читать, но перемещаться только вперёд и только однократно:

> - read
> - increment (without multiple passes)

Этот первый проход происходит при вызове `std::distance`, но так как итератор передаётся по значению (т.е. копируется при вызове функции), то первое значение `0.1` кешируется в исходном итераторе и выводится на первой итерации цикла при `*iter`. Последующий инкремент `++iter` приводит к тому, что итератор начинает указывать на ***end-of-stream***, т.е. за конец последовательности (тот самый, на который указывает итератор, созданный конструктором по умолчанию `std::istream_iterator<double>()`), и следовательно вторая и последующие итерации цикла приводят к [неопределённому поведению](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/900268/176217) (UB). В вашем случае это вырождается в четырёхкратный вывод `0.1`, но вполне может привести и к [ошибке сегментирования](https://wandbox.org/permlink/dujGoiSUR7YGTabp).

Если нужно по итератору ввода посчитать количество элементов и не потерять возможность чтения данных, то считать элементы нужно одновременно с их чтением. [Например](https://wandbox.org/permlink/IaDAMa1RakiZH4zf):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iterator>
int main()
{
    std::istringstream str("0.1 0.2 0.3 0.4");
    int n = 0;
    std::istream_iterator<double> iter(str);
    std::istream_iterator<double> eos;
    while (iter != eos) {
        std::cout << *iter << std::endl;
        ++iter;
        ++n;
    }
    std::cout << "size=" << n << "\n";
}
```