# Определение шаблонных аргументов std::initializer_list

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++, gcc, clang

В следующей программе аргументы шаблона определяются без проблем gcc и clang.

```
#include <vector>

int main() {
    std::vector x{1,2,3};
}
```

Однако здесь почему-то clang не может их определить, а gcc может ([godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/3b5n5v)):

```
#include <initializer_list>

int main() {
    std::initializer_list x{1,2,3};
}
```

Почему так? Кто прав?

Ошибка компиляции у clang:

> error: no viable constructor or deduction guide for deduction of
> template arguments of 'initializer_list'

Comment: Мне кажется кланг прав. Не могу найти никаких указаний, что CTAD должен работать для `initializer_list`.

Comment: Какая разница? =) Стандарт не регламентирует абсолютно всё. Часть реализации остаётся на усмотрение разработчиков компилятора. Нужно идти от обратного, если что-то не запрещено -- значит оно разрешено, так что тут нет правых и неправых.

Comment: @Πανμέτρονάριστον так если это implementation defined, то так и должно быть написано в стандарте. Если так и написано, то да — оба будут правы

Comment: @dIm0n, если ничего не написано, то это уже implementation defined =)

Comment: @Πανμέτρονάριστον Это так не работает. Во первых, "не написано" = неопределенное поведение, а не implementation defined (насколько я помню), а во вторых надо еще убедиться, что оно там не написано. Вдруг там после перечисления случаев, в которых работает CTAD, написно "если ни один пункт не подходит, то программа - ill-formed", или что-то в этом духе.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, я в русском языке не знаю как указать разницу между UB и ID. Так что я надеялся, что итак понятно.

Comment: @Πανμέτρονάριστον Так вы ж ниже прямым текстом написали, что имели в виду implementation defined.

Comment: @Πανμέτρονάριστον по поводу различий UB, ID есть такой [вопросик](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/900268/176217).

Comment: @αλεχολυτ, я знаю в чем разница, просто по-русски не всегда понятно как выразиться.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Class template argument deduction (CTAD) работает на основании существующих (специальных) правил вывода типа, а также имеющихся конструкторов класса.
Собственно об этом как раз говорит текст ошибки, приведённый в вопросе:

> error: no viable constructor or deduction guide for deduction of template arguments of 'initializer_list'

Для `std::vector` вывод основан на [конструкторе (9)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector):

```
vector(std::initializer_list<T> init, const Allocator& alloc = Allocator());
```

У `std::initializer_list` специальных правил вывода типа нет, а конструктор имеется [только один](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list/initializer_list) - для создания пустого списка. Таким образом, оснований для вывода типа в записи вида `std::initializer_list x{1,2,3};` нет.

Здесь, как я понимаю, сыграло роль то, что тип `std::initializer_list` в языке довольно особенный и создаётся неявно самим языком при наличии фигурных скобок в определённых контекстах. Но вот отдельного правила для вывода типа для него не предусмотрено. То, что gcc и msvc выводят тип может быть основано на том, что внутренне запись

```
std::initializer_list x{1,2,3};
```

интерпретируется как

```
std::initializer_list x = std::initializer_list<int>{1,2,3};
```

И тогда, конечно, вывод типа работает.

P.S. Некоторые идеи получены из [ответа на enSO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55207707/3240681).

Answer (score 2):

`std::vector` имеет конструктор, который принимает на вход `std::initializer_list`,  поэтому поведение как gcc так и clang никого не удивляет.
Но, давайте рассмотрим такой пример:

```
template <class T>
struct S {
  S(){}                              
  S(T, int, long){}                              
};

S<int> s1; //#1 
S s2(s1);  //#2
```

Обратите внимание на инициализацию #2. В данном случае выведение типа используется для конструктора копирования, сгенерированного компилятором по умолчанию. С этим кодом спокойно работает как gcc так и clang, так как, на сколько я вижу, все тут соответствует стандарту, и конструктор по умолчанию и CTAD.
Теперь применительно к `std::initializer_list`. Он также имеет конструктор копирования сгенерированный компилятором и соответственно может принимать в качестве параметра `std::initializer_list`. Поэтому инициализация `std::initializer_list`ничем не отличается от инициализации любого класса, который имеет конструктор с таким параметром. И тут также нет ничего противоречащего стандарту, по крайней мере я не увидел. С этим согласны большинство компиляторов кроме clang.
Данный код в clang не работает:

```
#include <initializer_list>

int main() {
    std::initializer_list x{1,2,3};
}
```

Но, если указать тип вручную

```
std::initializer_list<int> x{1,2,3};
```

то clang тут же обнаружит нужный конструктор. Также работоспособности можно добиться указав гайд (только для демонстрации поведения компилятора, использование где либо еще не рекомендуется):

```
namespace std {
     template<class T> initializer_list(const std::initializer_list<T>&) -> initializer_list<T>; 
 }
```

после этого CTAD начнет работать и в clang. Взято из комментариев к [этому ответу](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55205176/is-stdinitializer-listx-y-z-ctad-valid/55207707#55207707)
Посмотреть как это работает можно [здесь](https://godbolt.org/z/3MW189)

Вывод такой, что clang необоснованно не выводит тип в конструкторе копирования `std::initializer_list`. Т.е. в clang ошибка.

Comment: Здесь есть пара вопросов: [разрешены ли вообще пользовательские гайды для std типов](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63424573/3240681) и должна ли запись вида `std::initializer_list x{1,2,3};` интерпретироваться как вызов копирующего конструктора (всё же это *list-initialization*).

Comment: @αλεχολυτ Гайд для демонстрации поведения компилятора и никак не руководство к действию. И, да, запись подобного вида для нетривиальных объектов интерпретируется как вызов [конструктора](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.match.ctor). "For copy-initialization (including default initialization in the context of copy-initialization), the candidate functions are all the converting constructors ([class.conv.ctor]) of that class" [В продолжение](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.conv.ctor#1). Там в принципе есть перекрестные ссылки.

Comment: Так а почему это должно быть *copy-initialization*? Я вот считаю, что это *direct-initialization*. Например, вот [здесь](https://wandbox.org/permlink/vrE6zKReYUqDP1ZJ) никакого копирования объекта нет, а есть прямая инициализация.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ Да, если это возможно для тривиального объекта, но если мы допишем подходящий конструктор, то вызовется он https://godbolt.org/z/zsaTfx. Вообще это уже совсем другой вопрос.