# Указатели в функции

Tags: c++, функции, указатели

```
int* one(){
  int *a = nullptr;
  int x = 2;
  a = &x;
  cout<<a<<endl;
  return a;
}

int main(){
  int *b = one();
  cout<<b;
}
```

Мой вопрос в том, что указатель b указывает на область памяти, в которой хранится переменная x. Но после завершения выполнения функции у нас вроде бы исчезает переменная x. И на что теперь указывает указатель b, если переменной x больше не существует. Хотелось бы узнать что вообще происходит с переменными, указателями и памятью.

Answer (score 3):

как я понимаю память же никуда не девается - будет указывать на то месте в памяти, где когда-то была переменная `X`, а что в этом месте сейчас (после завершения функции) решает уже ОС, компилятор и прочие чёрные ящики для программиста

может там будет лежать `2` до поры до времени, но когда данные будут изменены и на что науке не известно

Answer (score 1):

По завершении работы функции или при выходе из блока, хранилище (*storage*, область памяти в которой располагаются объекты) для объектов с автоматической продолжительностью хранения (*automatic storage duration*, обычные локальные переменные) перестаёт существовать.

Любой указатель, указывавший на любой байт уничтоженного хранилища, принимает невалидное значение (*invalid pointer value*). Разыменование невалидного указателя и передача его в функцию освобождения памяти приводят к неопределённому поведению ([undefined behavior](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/900292)).

Любое другое использование невалидного указательного значения приводит к поведению, определяемому реализацией (*implementation-defined behavior*). Например, копирование такого значения (`int *b = one();`) может приводить к аварийному завершению работы программы.

[basic.stc.general / 4](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.stc#general-4):

> When the end of the duration of a region of storage is reached, the values of all pointers representing the address of any part of that region of storage become invalid pointer values.
> Indirection through an invalid pointer value and passing an invalid pointer value to a deallocation function have undefined behavior.
> Any other use of an invalid pointer value has implementation-defined behavior.<sup>26</sup>
>
> 26. Some implementations might define that copying an invalid pointer value causes a system-generated runtime fault.

---

Рассмотрим код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

using std::cout; using std::endl;

int main()
{
    int* a = nullptr;
    int* b = nullptr;
    
    {
        int x = 0;
        a = &x;
    }
    {
        int x = 0;
        b = &x;
    }
    
    cout << std::boolalpha;
    cout << ( a == b ) << endl;
    cout << ( std::memcmp(&a, &b, sizeof(a)) == 0 ) << endl;
}
```

Возможный вывод ([g++](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/10ad6c2e454a8623)):

```
false
true
```

Программа конечно свою работу аварийно не завершила, но от этого не легче. Два невалидных указателя одновременно равны и не равны друг другу...

Comment: Ну, это все из стандартов. К счастью, реальность пока более определенна и описана в ответе @Zhihar