# Обработанное исключение в деструкторе

Tags: c++, исключения, language-lawyer, деструктор

Широко известно, что в деструкторе нельзя бросать исключения. Потому что если идет разворачивание стека и тут деструктор, то — читай http://eel.is/c++draft/except.terminate#1.4

Это понятно. Но если исключение и бросается, и перехватывается в самом деструкторе, не выходя - то что говорит стандарт по этому поводу? Здесь говорится только о `terminate()`, а вдруг это просто UB?

Я проверил на G++ и VC++ - проблем не возникает. Но есть ли явное упоминание в стандарте, что такое разрешено - бросать исключение во время обработки исключения, если только оно будет перехвачено?

Comment: "Destructor operations defined in the C++ standard library shall not throw exceptions. Every destructor in the C++ standard library shall behave as if it had a non-throwing exception specification." Но non-throwing exception specification вполне может быть у функции, которая генерирует и перехватывает исключение в своем теле. Более того, вы даже можете об этом и не знать, если исключение глубоко вложено. Так что склоняюсь к тому, что такая генерация не запрещена.

Comment: В 1.4 ничего не говорится про запрет на бросание исключений. Дословный перевод: `когда разрушение объекта во время раскрутки стека *завершается* выдачей исключения, `. Т.е. бросать исключения не запрещено. Запрещено их выбрасывать из тела деструктора.

Comment: По вашей же ссылке: «(1.4) when the destruction of an object during stack unwinding *terminates* by throwing an exception». То есть играет роль лишь то, как именно мы выходим из деструктора.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Во всём разделе [Exception handling](http://eel.is/c++draft/except) упоминание "undefined behavior" встречается только однажды: [при использовании нестатических членов класса в обработчике function-try-block конструтора](http://eel.is/c++draft/except#handle-10):

> Referring to any non-static member or base class of an object in the handler for a function-try-block of a constructor or destructor for that object results in undefined behavior.

Т.о. даже если не вдаваться в подробности, об UB в вашем случае речи нет.

Прямых слов о том, что в процессе раскрутки стека в деструкторе может быть вызвано и обработано новое исключение, я в стандарте не нашёл. Однако, есть [заметка](http://eel.is/c++draft/except#throw-note-5):

> If a destructor directly invoked by stack unwinding exits via an exception, `std​::​terminate` is invoked.

Мой перевод:

> Если деструктор, вызванный напрямую раскруткой стека, завершится исключением, то будет вызвано `std​::​terminate`.

Логично предположить, что если деструктор не завершается исключением (в том числе, если вызвать и тут же обработать его), то к вызову `std::terminate` это не приведёт. С неопределённым поведением сложнее, т.к. формально, если явно не описано поведение, то [может ожидаться неявное неопределённое](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/900292/176217). На данный случай это всё же вряд ли распространяется, т.к. подход с перехватом исключения в деструкторе описан в том числе и в C++ Super-FAQ на [isocpp.org](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/exceptions#ctor-exceptions):

> You can throw an exception in a destructor, but that exception must not leave the destructor;

Почему вообще исключениям в деструкторе уделяется такое внимание? Деструктор автоматически неявно вызывается в двух случаях:

- при **нормальном** завершении жизни объекта (при выходе из блока, если объект создан на стеке; или при вызове `delete`, если создан через `new`);
- при **аварийном** выходе из блока по исключению (т.н. раскрутка стека).

В последнем случае добавление нового исключения в деструкторе (без его обработки там же) приведёт к тому, что оно как бы будет улетать к обработчику первичного исключения. Однако, что в этом случае там делать с присутствующими одновременно двумя исключениями совершенно непонятно, поэтому в стандарте принято решение просто сдаться и завершить программу через `std::terminate`.

Если же исключение, возникшее в деструкторе, в нём же и обработать, то даже при раскрутке стека (наличии первичного исключения) ситуации, что один обработчик (т.е. `catch` блок) столкнётся с двумя активными исключениями, не возникнет. Поведение программы при этом может быть реализовано вполне понятным образом.

Вообще, выкидывать исключения из деструктора наружу можно. Как минимум надо  добавить `noexcept(false)`, т.к. по умолчанию деструкторы неявно считаются невыкидивающими исключений. Но главное - это убедиться, что мы не находимся в этот момент в режиме раскрутки стека. Примерно так:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <exception>

struct X {
    X() : except_count(std::uncaught_exceptions()) {}
    ~X() noexcept(false) { 
        if (except_count == std::uncaught_exceptions()) {
            std::cout << "X can throw in destructor\n";
            throw 1; 
        }
        std::cout << "X stack unwinding, can't throw out\n";
    }
    
    int except_count;
};

int main() {
    try {
        X x;
        throw 2; // в зависимости от наличия этой строки будем попадать в разные ветки
    }
    catch(...) {
        std::cout << "caught in main\n";
    }
}
```

Самое сложное здесь, это обеспечить, что исключение может покинуть деструктор только в соответствующем блоке с проверкой, а также что в этом блоке нет других вложенных объектов, выкидывающих исключение из своего деструктора, не опираясь на схожую проверку наличия активной раскрутки стека. Иначе всё это снова приведёт к необработанным исключениям и `std::terminate` в итоге. Так что намного проще не допускать выхода исключений из деструктора.

В целом, сложности использования исключений в деструкторах в C++ возникают из-за того, что при генерации исключения сначала происходит раскрутка стека, и только потом мы попадаем в обработчик. Если бы мы попадали в обработчик сразу, и откладывали раскрутку стека на потом, двойных активных исключений можно было бы избежать.

Comment: Ладно, сформулирую по другому: в стандарте есть явное указание, что обработчик исключения может быть вложенным? Что во время обработки внешнего исключения может быть сгенерировано, перехвачено и обработано другое исключение? Другим, вложенным перехватчиком try-catch?

Comment: @Mikhailo обновил ответ.

Comment: Честно говоря, четкого ответа не получил, но я вам верю, что все в порядке :)

Comment: @Mikhailo четкого ответа даже на [enSO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70327434/3240681) не получить.