# const_cast объясните почему одинаковые адреса но значения разные

Tags: c++, const

const_cast снимающий нижнюю константность не изменяет исходный объект, с этим вопросов нет. Вопрос именно в другом:

```
const int i = 123;
const int* pci = &i;
int* pi = const_cast<int*>(pci);
cout << "i&:\t" << pci <<  " " << i << "\npci\t" << pci << " " << *pci << "\npi\t" << pi << " " << *pi << "\n***********" << endl;
*pi = 55;
cout << "i&:\t" << pci <<  " " << i << "\npci\t" << pci << " " << *pci << "\npi\t" << pi << " " << *pi << "\n***********" << endl;
*(const_cast<int*>(&i)) = 888;
cout << "i&:\t" << pci <<  " " << i << "\npci\t" << pci << " " << *pci << "\npi\t" << pi << " " << *pi << "\n***********" << endl;
```

почему адреса исходного объекта, а так же двух указателей совпадают, хотя в них лежат разные значения?
Изначально Я думал что адреса будут одинаковыми пока мы не изменим значение через const_cast или через указатель на не константу, но как видно из результата работы программы, обращение идёт по одному адресу.

Comment: Потому что изменение константы - UB. А дальше можно гадать: например, компилятор соптимизировал код, ожидая константу и выводит не значение из ячейки переменной, а просто литерал. И т.д.

Comment: так константа и не изменилась. Изменилось содержимой по содержимому в указателе на не константу, хотя адрес одинаковый. код выполняет данные действия, и демонстрирует это.

Comment: Единственное, что код демонстрирует - это наличие неопределенного поведения. В С++ невозможно определить валидность конструкций по результатам работы программы. http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/900268

Comment: Мне код продемонстрировал что по разыменованным указателям, которые позволяют изменять значение, лежат те значения которые указал. По сути правильно ведь было бы так: что хоть и было изменено через pi значение, но вывод того что находится по адресу должен быть не изменённым. Правильно ведь?

Comment: *"правильно ведь было бы так: что хоть и было изменено через pi значение, но вывод того что находится по адресу должен быть не изменённым"* - нет, поведение этого действия не определено. Код даже не обязан собираться в таком виде, или может вместо вывода заказать пиццу.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не пойму, что удивляет? Все указатели — что `pci`, что `pi` — указывают на `i`, и равны `&i`. Это к первому столбцу вывода. Где все адреса одинаковы.

Второй столбец: при выводе `i` компилятор ориентируется на то, что это константа, и выводит *именно константу, а не значение переменной*. Готов спорить, что при просмотре сгенерированного кода там не будет никакого обращения к памяти.

А два последних значения получаются через разыменование.

Только вот несмотря на то, что мы получаем указатель на неконстантную величину при применении `const_cast`, **менять ее категорически не следует!** Не для этой цели `const_cast` придумали...

P.S. Вот, посмотрите: https://godbolt.org/z/d17a6EWY6

Как видите, после всех изменений значений по адресу все равно получаем при выводе:

```
mov     esi, 123
mov     rdi, rax
call    std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >::operator<<(int)
```

т.е. он просто выводит 123, не интересуясь, что там на самом деле в переменной записано.

Comment: на win10 visual studio, вывод показывает то, что описывается в вопросе. Видимо так работает именно на той ОС и с тем компилятором, который мной использован. То есть, если бы использовал другие ОС с другими компиляторами, то вывод был бы более правильным, и придерживался стандарта. Я вроде припоминаю такое, что когда изменял переменную через указатель который указывал на не константу, то переменная оставалась изначальной.

Comment: А **вывод** в вопросе не показан, кстати :) Вот такой? https://ideone.com/Yz2Ram - это GCC. https://godbolt.org/z/Mc8nhjG6h - Clang. *когда изменял переменную через указатель который указывал на не константу* — важнее вопрос, эта переменная объявлена как константная или нет. Еще раз: компилятор, видя объявление константной переменной, вполне может заменить обращение  ней просто на значение этой константы, не обращаясь к памяти.

Comment: да, именно такой вывод был у Меня как указано по ссылке. Спасибо за объяснения.